# How can I use IStringLocalizer<T> with {}.en.resx in my console app?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, localization, .net-core, console-application

I've got a .NET Core Console App that shares some common libraries with my ASP.NET Core App.  I need to add Globalization to the common project and in ASP.NET I can easily create a new .resx file with the language `some.en.resx`

At the moment, I can register my service, and it is calling the StringLocalizer class but not returning the localised string.  I managed to get it working by removing the `.en` from the file, but then that breaks my ASP.NET project.

Its like I need to register a default Language somewhere, but I can't work out where.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<MyService>();
        serviceCollection.AddSingleton<LoggerFactory>();

        serviceCollection
            .AddLogging()
            .AddLocalization();

        ServiceProvider buildServiceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        MyService myService = buildServiceProvider.GetService<MyService>();
        string greeting = myService.GetGreeting();
        Console.WriteLine(greeting);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class MyService
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<MyService> _stringLocalizer;

    public MyService(IStringLocalizer<MyService> stringLocalizer)
    {
        _stringLocalizer = stringLocalizer;
    }

    public string GetGreeting()
    {
        return _stringLocalizer.GetString("Greeting");
    }
}
```

[image]

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Did it really work without .en in the file name, returning the text "Hello" and not "Greeting"? If so, can you upload your complete test project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't managed to find a way of repeating the behaviour of ASP.NET.  I've had to accept that I can't have .en.resx files and luckily with a Culture of "en" ASP.NET uses the default .resx files